# R check if values in row are equal

Tags: r

I have data in the following format:

[image: image1]

what I want to do is check in each row whether the value in pred is = to the one in obs

so in the example above 3 out of 5 are equal and the accuracy would be 60% ?

How can I do that?

Screenshot of code:

[image: image2]

Comment: `df$pred == df$obs`. You can take the `mean` of that result to get the overall accuracy.

Comment: Error in prediction$pred : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

Comment: Replace `df` with the name of your data frame. For example `my_data_frame_name_here$pred == my_data_frame_name_here$obs`. It seems like you maybe already pulled the `prediction` out into its own vector named prediction? If so, you could use `prediction == my_data_frame_name$obs`, but it's probably better to keep it within the data frame in your picture.

Comment: library(caret)
train_control <- trainControl(method="cv", number=10, savePredictions = TRUE)
model_cv <- train(as.factor(R1)~., data=data_matrix, trControl=train_control, method="rpart")
model_cv$pred
prediction = table(model_cv$pred)
sum(prediction["pred"] == prediction["obs"]/nrow(prediction)

Comment: this doesn't look good how can I make it look like code. I'll take a screenshot

Comment: added the screenshot to the original post

Comment: Please add code to your original post, not in comments and not as a screenshot.  See [formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) if you need assistance.  For that matter, it's best if you can provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) - that makes it easiest to help you, and clearest for others who view your post looking for answers to a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your data frame is called "prediction".

The `==` operation takes each element if the vectors are of equal lengths and compares them, returning a TRUE or FALSE. When performing arithmetic on TRUEs and FALSEs they're treated like 1s and 0s respectively. As such the mean of this `==` comparison will give you what you want.

```
mean(prediction[["pred"]]==prediction[["obs"]])
```

Comment: if I do View(prediction["pred"]) it gives me a blank sheet

Comment: I solved it! just had to use as.data.frame instead of table as prediction was a value and now it's a dataframe

Comment: You're absolutely right, I just went straight from his code without thinking too much about it! Thank you :)